# How to test the render speed of my solution in a web browser?

Tags: optimization, rendering, benchmarking, load-testing

Ok, I need to test the speed of my solution in a web browser, but I have some problems, there are 2 versions of the web solution, the original one that is on server A and the "fixed" version that is on server B.

I have VS2010 Ultimate, so I can make a web and load test on solution B, but I can't load the A solution on my IDE.

I was trying to use [fiddle2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), but they only gave me the times of the request and response of the browsers with the server, I also want the time it takes to the browser to render the whole page.

Maybe I'm misusing some of this tools...

I don't know if this could be usefull but:

- Solution A is on VB 6.0
- Solution B is on VB.Net

It needs to work in IE, FF, Chrome, Opera and Safari

Comment: Not a complete benchmarking suite, but YSlow might be a Firefox plugin of interest to you.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I can't use it on IE

Answer (score 1):

Application Performance Management if your org already has is the best for this.  You will be after their javascript injection technology.  Basically it adds javascript to the web page and measures metrics, mostly using Navigation Timings API.

https://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/

Nav Timings will give you metrics like, network load time, dom construction time, and page render time.

I'm guessing you are probably not looking to spend any money though.  I have not used this open source library, but it says it will take navigation timings for you.  Might be worth checking out.

https://github.com/sitespeedio/sitespeed.io

Answer (score 0):

YSlow is great in firefox, as is PageSpeed in google, but these are browser specific.

You might look at JQuery as it has a $(document).ready which will run some  javascript upon the document being loaded. This should enable you to time when the page is done loading across different browsers.

Another option would be to use [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). There is a discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/selenium-test-tool/zR_U57obJz8 that might be helpful.

Comment: YSlow works in almost all browsers, except for IE, http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/ I can't make changes on A solution nor adding .js files

Comment: That's a good discussion, a little bit outdated, but with good content, lemme check on selenium and see if that could help me out. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in your question. To get the page load time of a site in a browser you should use a browser. Not only is a browser going to be the most accurate representation of a browser but you'd be surprised at how hard it is to get a synthetic tool to record a true, subjective figure for page load time. If you also want data for FF, Chrome etc, then install them and use them. The best (only?) approach for cross-browser page load tuning is to repeat the tests across multiple browsers!

So, that's client-side stuff (aka WPO).

For the server, you could se a tool like JMeter, this would load your server, not your client. You want to test your server separately to your client and when you are testing the server, you should focus on the server and pretty much ignore the client. JMeter and it's friends are not browsers but they are very good at simulating the *server calls* that come from browsers and it is at this level (the HTTP level) that this task should be performed. So, to recap, this is *server* focused activity, not client.

Once you've done all that then, yes, client-side tools can be useful for automation and regression but they're really only useful for when you've already tuned things.

Reasons why sythentic tools aren't as good as a stopwatch and a human brain.

1. Most tools will record how long it takes to load everything but these days that's not always the same as the user experience. We make great efforts to push loading things to the background or bottom of the page (below the fold) but synthetic tools don't see these things.
2. In the same vein, js and images might still be loading but from the users perspective the page is complete. A tool would not see this, a human brain would.
3. The *way* a page loads can be subtly different which might not make much difference to the human experience but could cause a tool to throw a hissy fit. Eg. A third-party call might timeout but if this does not block the page it might not even be seen by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to answer a Layer 7 question (GUI), then use a layer 7 tool, like Selenium

Answer (score 0):

The buzzword you are looking for is [Application Performance Monitoring/Management (APM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) ... specifically solutions including cross-browser user experience metrics for a rendered web page.

There are a few ways to instrument web applications, but your requirement for classic VB 6.0 does limit the options.

Some possibilities to consider:

- A simple approach would be to add web page analytics (eg [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), [Piwik](http://piwik.org/), ...) which include rendered page load times and let you segment by specific browser versions and operating systems. The typical level of integration is a JavaScript include in your web application.
- For more modern frameworks like .NET, there are also specific APM tools like [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) and [Application Dynamics](http://www.appdynamics.com/).  These generally approach performance measurement starting from the app, database, and server level and extend to the end user experience.  The typical level of integration is via a web server module and/or agent that runs on your server.

There are also a number of browser-specific plugins, but those will generally require manual data collection for each test run .. and not be overly helpful in comparing cross-browser performance because the measurement methodology differs.